# Why components added to JPanel, the panel can be shown, but when components added into frame first, the panel cannot be shown

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to let user select one at a time a song to be played along with a rendered moving score. I wish user can chose a song and click "PLAY" button to start it. Therefore, I want to put a `JComboBox` in `JFrame` and each time when user select a song, I can render a corresponding `JPanel` for the moving score. But when I put the combo box and other components into a frame, the panel cannot be shown.

The code for putting those components in a panel is listed below:

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.IOException; 

class MyPanel extends JPanel{   
    public int x[] = new int[59]; 
    public int y[] = new int[59]; 
    public int width[] = new int[59];
    public int height = 20;
    Color color[] = new Color[59];//the color of each note

    String[] lyric = {"一", " 根", "紫～", "竹", "直～", "苗～", "苗,", "送", "給", "寶", "寶", "做", "管", "簫,",
                      "簫", "兒", "對", "準", "口,", "口", "兒", "對", "準", "簫,", 
                      "簫～", "中", "吹～", "出", "新～", "時～ ", "調,",
                      "小", "寶～", "寶,", "小", "寶～", "寶,", 
                      "咿", "底", "咿", "底", "學 ", "會", "了,", "啊 ～     ～    ～"};//共45個

    int[] numNotes = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                      1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6};//共45個

    int[][] notes = {{5,2},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},{2,1},{1,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{5,1},{6,2},{3,2},{5,8},{8,1},{6,1},{3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{5,1},{6,1},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},
                     {2,1},{1,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {6,1},{8,1},{9,2},{6,2},{5,3},{6,1},{2,1},{3,1},{5,1},{6,1},{5,8}};//共59個

    String[] simplifiedNote = {"| 5", "  1", " 6", "5", "3", "| 5", "2", "3", "2", "1  - ", "| 6", "1", 
                               "3", "5", "6", " 3", " 5  -  -  -", "| 1", "6", "3", "6", "5  - ", "| 6", "1", 
                               "3", "6", "5  -", "| 5", "6", "1", "6", "5", " 3", "| 5", "2", "3",
                               "2", "1   -", "| 1", "1", "3", "2   -", "| 1", "1", "3", "2  -", "| 6", "1", 
                               "6", "1", "2", "6", "| 5   .", "6", "2", "3", "5", "6", "| 5  -  -  - "};//共59個

    Color color0 = new Color(255,255,255); //白色 
    Color color1 = new Color(255,0,0); //紅色
    Color color2 = new Color(255,165,0); //橙色
    Color color3 = new Color(255,255,0); //黃色
    Color color4 = new Color(0,128,0); //綠色
    Color color5 = new Color(0,0,255); //藍色
    Color color6 = new Color(75,0,130); //靛色
    Color color7 = new Color(100,0,153); //紫色
    Color color8 = new Color(153,0,0); //暗紅
    Color color9 = new Color(0,0,0); //黑色

    public void display(){
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("notes[" + i + "][0] = " + notes[i][0]);
            switch (notes[i][0]) {
                case 1:
                     y[i] = 400;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 2:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20;
                     color[i] = color2;
                     break;
                case 3:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*2;
                     color[i] = color3;
                     break;
                case 4:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*3;
                     color[i] = color4;
                     break;
                case 5:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*4;
                     color[i] = color5;
                     break;
                case 6:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*5;
                     color[i] = color6;
                     break;
                case 7:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*6;
                     color[i] = color7;
                     break;
                case 8:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*7;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 9:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*8;
                     color[i] = color2;
            }

            switch (notes[i][1]) {
                case 1: width[i] = 20;     
                        break;
                case 2: width[i] = 20 * 2; 
                        break;
                case 3: width[i] = 20 * 3; 
                        break;
                case 4: width[i] = 20 * 4; 
                        break;
                case 5: width[i] = 20 * 5; 
                        break;
                case 6: width[i] = 20 * 6; 
                        break;
                case 7: width[i] = 20 * 7; 
                        break;
                case 8: width[i] = 20 * 8;
            }
        }

        x[0] = 100;
        for (int i = 1; i < notes.length; i++){
             x[i] = x[i-1] + width[i-1];
        }

        int timeLast = 0;
        //timeLast = total executing time
        while(timeLast < 900){ 
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++){
                x[i]--;
            }
            this.repaint(); 
            try {Thread.sleep(155);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timeLast = timeLast + 1; 
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);    
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 20));

        int y1 = 130; //C調 4/4 Y坐標
        int y2 = 180; //簡譜行Y坐標
        int y3 = 210; //歌詞行Y坐標
        int y4 = 163; //加高音點
        int y5 = 180; //加八分音符底線
        int y6 = 470; //色彩音符說明

        int chrPosition = 0;
        g2d.drawString("C調  4/4", 16, y1);

        //繪出最底下的色彩音符說明
        g2d.drawString("色彩音符說明：", 16, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color1);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(176, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Do", 200, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color2);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(256, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//220 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Re", 280, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color3);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(336, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//230 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Mi", 360, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color4);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(416, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//322 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Fa", 440, y6);//366 + 24

        g2d.setColor(color5);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(496, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//390 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": So", 520, y6);//446 + 24

        g2d.setColor(color6);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(576, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//470 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": La", 600, y6);

        //寫出簡譜
        for (int i = 0;i < simplifiedNote.length; i++){

            g2d.drawString(simplifiedNote[i], x[i], y2);
        }

        //在簡譜下方寫出歌詞
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        for (int i = 0;  i < lyric.length; i++){
            if (i != 0 && numNotes[i-1] == 2) {
                chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            else {
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
        }

        //在簡譜上方加高音點
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[1]+14, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[11]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[17]+11, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[23]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[29]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[47]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[49]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[50]+2, y4);

        //在簡譜下方加八分音符底線
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[2]+4, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[3], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[5]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[6], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[7], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[8], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[10]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[11], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[12], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[13], y5);//10
        g2d.drawString("_", x[17]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[18], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[19], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[20], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[22]+8, y5);//15
        g2d.drawString("_", x[23], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[24], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[25], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[27]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[28], y5);//20
        g2d.drawString("_", x[30], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[31], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[33]+8, y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[34], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[35], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[36], y5);//25
        g2d.drawString("_", x[39], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[40], y5);
        g2d.drawString("_", x[43], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[44], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[46]+8, y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[47], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[48], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[49], y5);//1
        g2d.drawString("_", x[53], y5);//6
        g2d.drawString("_", x[54], y5);//2
        g2d.drawString("_", x[55], y5);//3
        g2d.drawString("_", x[56], y5);//5
        g2d.drawString("_", x[57], y5);//6

        //在歌詞下方繪出彩色譜        
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++){

            g2d.setColor(color[i]);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(x[i], y[i], width[i], height, 3,3); //畫圓角方塊

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],230, x[i]+width[i], 230);//畫水平上線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],231, x[i], 429);//畫直紅線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],430, x[i]+width[i], 430);//畫水平下線
        }
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1],231, x[notes.length - 1] + width[notes.length - 1],429);//畫邊界直紅線
    }
}

public class Test7 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
        JFrame  jf = new JFrame("康樂彩歌");
        jf.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 730);      
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyPanel jp = new MyPanel();
        //jp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("選歌：");    //創建標簽
        label1.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        JComboBox cmbox = new JComboBox();    //創建JComboBox
        cmbox.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        cmbox.addItem("紫竹調");
        cmbox.addItem("走一同去郊遊");
        cmbox.addItem("我家門前有小河");

        JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("加人聲", false);
        rb1.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        JButton btPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btPlay.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));

        jp.add(label1);
        jp.add(cmbox);
        jp.add(rb1);
        jp.add(btPlay);

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.add(jp); 
        jp.display();
    }
}
```

And the code for putting those components in a frame is listed below:

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.IOException; 

class Panel1 extends JPanel{    
    public int x[] = new int[59]; 
    public int y[] = new int[59]; 
    public int width[] = new int[59];
    public int height = 20;
    Color color[] = new Color[59];//the color of each note

    //一根紫 竹 直 苗 苗,      5  ?  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─ 
    //送給寶寶做管 簫,      6 ?   3 5  6 3 │5 ─ ─ ─
    //簫兒對準口,            ? 6 3 6 5 ─ 
    //口兒對準簫,           6 5 3 6  5 ─
    //簫 中吹 出  新 時 調, 56  ?  65 3 │ 52 32 1 ─
    //小寶寶, 小寶 寶,      1 13 2 ─  | 1 13 2  ─   
    //咿底 咿底學會了.啊～～  6 ?   6  ?  2 6 | 5 . 6  23 56│ 5 ─ ─ ─

    String[] lyric = {" 一", " 根", "紫～", "竹", "直～", "苗～", "苗,",
                      "送", "給", "寶", "寶", "做", "管", " 簫,",
                      "簫", "兒", "對", "準", "口,", "口", "兒", "對", "準", "簫,", 
                      "簫～", "中", "吹～", "出", "新～", "時～ ", "調,",
                      "小", "寶～", "寶,", "小", "寶～", "寶,", 
                      "咿", "底", "咿", "底", " 學 ", "會", "了,", "啊 ～     ～    ～"};//共45個

    int[] numNotes = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                      1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6};//共45個

    int[][] notes = {{5,2},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},{2,1},{1,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{5,1},{6,2},{3,2},{5,8},{8,1},{6,1},{3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{6,1},{5,1},
                     {3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{5,1},{6,1},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},
                     {2,1},{1,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {6,1},{8,1},{9,2},{6,2},{5,3},{6,1},{2,1},{3,1},{5,1},{6,1},{5,8}};//共59個

    String[] simplifiedNote = {"  5", "  1", " 6", "5", "3", "  5", " 2", " 3", "2", "1  - ",
                               "  6", " 1"," 3", " 5", " 6", " 3", "  5  -  -  -", 
                               " 1", " 6", " 3", " 6", " 5  - ", " 6", " 5", " 3", " 6", " 5  -",
                               " 5", " 6", " 1", " 6", "5", " 3", " 5", "2", " 3"," 2", "1   -", 
                               " 1", " 1", "3", "2   -", " 1", " 1", "3", "2  -",
                               " 6", "1","6", "1", " 2", "6", " 5 ．", "6", 
                               " 2", "3", " 5", "6", " 5  -  -  - "};//共59個

    Color color0 = new Color(255,255,255); //白色 
    Color color1 = new Color(255,0,0); //紅色
    Color color2 = new Color(255,165,0); //橙色
    Color color3 = new Color(255,255,0); //黃色
    Color color4 = new Color(0,128,0); //綠色
    Color color5 = new Color(0,0,255); //藍色
    Color color6 = new Color(75,0,130); //靛色
    Color color7 = new Color(100,0,153); //紫色
    Color color8 = new Color(153,0,0); //暗紅
    Color color9 = new Color(0,0,0); //黑色

    //Constructor for initializing the color, y position, width, length of each note
    Panel1(){
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("notes[" + i + "][0] = " + notes[i][0]);
            switch (notes[i][0]) {
                case 1:
                     y[i] = 400;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 2:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20;
                     color[i] = color2;
                     break;
                case 3:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*2;
                     color[i] = color3;
                     break;
                case 4:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*3;
                     color[i] = color4;
                     break;
                case 5:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*4;
                     color[i] = color5;
                     break;
                case 6:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*5;
                     color[i] = color6;
                     break;
                case 7:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*6;
                     color[i] = color7;
                     break;
                case 8:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*7;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 9:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*8;
                     color[i] = color2;
            }

            switch (notes[i][1]) {
                case 1: width[i] = 20;     
                        break;
                case 2: width[i] = 20 * 2; 
                        break;
                case 3: width[i] = 20 * 3; 
                        break;
                case 4: width[i] = 20 * 4; 
                        break;
                case 5: width[i] = 20 * 5; 
                        break;
                case 6: width[i] = 20 * 6; 
                        break;
                case 7: width[i] = 20 * 7; 
                        break;
                case 8: width[i] = 20 * 8;
            }
        }

        x[0] = 100;
        for (int i = 1; i < notes.length; i++){
             x[i] = x[i-1] + width[i-1];
        }
    }

    public void display1(){
        //*
        int timeLast = 0;
        //timeLast = total executing time
        while(timeLast < 1000){ 
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++){
                x[i]--;
            }
            this.repaint(); 
            try {Thread.sleep(30);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timeLast = timeLast + 1; 
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);    
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 20));

        int y1 = 130; //C調 4/4 Y坐標
        int y2 = 180; //簡譜行Y坐標
        int y3 = 210; //歌詞行Y坐標
        int y4 = 163; //加高音點
        int y5 = 180; //加八分音符底線
        int y6 = 470; //色彩音符說明

        int chrPosition = 0;
        g2d.drawString("C調  4/4", 16, y1);

        //繪出最底下的色彩音符說明
        g2d.drawString("色彩音符說明：", 16, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color1);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(176, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Do", 200, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color2);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(256, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//220 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Re", 280, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color3);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(336, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//230 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Mi", 360, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color4);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(416, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//322 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Fa", 440, y6);//366 + 24

        g2d.setColor(color5);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(496, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//390 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": So", 520, y6);//446 + 24

        g2d.setColor(color6);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(576, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//470 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": La", 600, y6);

        //在簡譜下方寫出歌詞
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        for (int i = 0;  i < lyric.length; i++){
            if (i != 0 && numNotes[i-1] == 2) {
                chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            else {
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
        }

        //在簡譜上方加高音點
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[1]+14, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[11]+8, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[17]+7, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[29]+8, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[47]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[49]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[50]+8, y4);
        //*
        //在簡譜下方加八分音符底線
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[2]+5,y5+5,x[4]-10,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[5]+10,y5+5,x[7]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[7]+3,y5+5,x[9]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[10]+10,y5+5,x[11],y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[11]+5,y5+5,x[12]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[12]+5,y5+5,x[13]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[13]+5,y5+5,x[14]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[17]+5,y5+4,x[18]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[18]+5,y5+4,x[19]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[19]+5,y5+4,x[20]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[20]+5,y5+4,x[21]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[22]+5,y5+5,x[23]-2,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[23]+5,y5+5,x[24]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[24]+5,y5+5,x[25]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[25]+5,y5+5,x[26]-5,y5+5);

        g2d.drawLine(x[27]+5,y5+5,x[29]-3,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[30]+1,y5+5,x[32]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[33]+5,y5+4,x[35]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[35]+5,y5+4,x[37]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[39]+5,y5+4,x[41]-8,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[43]+5,y5+5,x[45]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[46]+5,y5+5,x[47]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[47],y5+5,x[48]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[48],y5+5,x[49]-10,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[49],y5+5,x[50]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[53]-2,y5+4,x[58]-5,y5+4);

        //在歌詞下方繪出彩色譜        
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++){

            //畫簡譜小節線
            g2d.setColor(color9);
            if (i==0||i==5||i==10||i==16||i==17||i==22||i==27||i==33||i==38||
                i==42||i==46||i == 52||i == 58) {
                g2d.drawString("|", x[i], y2);
                }

            //畫出簡譜
            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawString(simplifiedNote[i], x[i], y2);

            g2d.setColor(color[i]);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(x[i], y[i], width[i], height, 3,3); //畫圓角方塊

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],230, x[i]+width[i], 230);//畫水平上線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],231, x[i], 429);//畫直紅線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],430, x[i]+width[i], 430);//畫水平下線
        }
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString("|",x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1]-5 , y2);
        g2d.drawString("|",x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1]-10 , y2);
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1],231, x[notes.length - 1] + width[notes.length - 1],429);//畫邊界直紅線
    }
}

public class Move1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
        JFrame  jf = new JFrame("康樂彩歌(v0)");
        jf.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 730);      
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(null);

        Panel1 jp1 = new Panel1();
        //jp.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        jp1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JComboBox cmbox = new JComboBox();
        cmbox.setBounds(10, 40, 250, 40);
        cmbox.setLocation(370,25);
        cmbox.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        cmbox.addItem("紫竹調");
        cmbox.addItem("走一同去郊遊");
        cmbox.addItem("我家門前有小河");
        jf.add(cmbox);

        JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("加人聲", false);
        rb2.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        rb2.setBounds(635, 28, 90, 30);
        jf.add(rb2);

        JButton btPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btPlay.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));
        btPlay.setBounds(740, 25, 100, 40);
        jf.add(btPlay);

        JButton btStop = new JButton("STOP");
        btStop.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));
        btStop.setBounds(850, 25, 100, 40);
        jf.add(btStop);

        jf.setVisible(true);

//        btPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//?按?添加事件接收器
//             @Override
//             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//接受到事件后,?行下面的?理
//              //System.out.println("Hello World");// 控制台打印?出
//              //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");// ?出??框,?示Hello World
//             }
//            });
        jf.add(jp1);
        jp1.display1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not set the frame visible until you have added everything to it. Literally move `jf.setVisible(true);` after `jf.add(jp1);` - And I think you want to rely on the `repaint()` method when updating the contents of your panel. There is a bit of a language barrier in that I can't really follow everything you have said in your question, but your English is infinitely better than my command of your language. If that doesn't solve the problem, please try and create a more minimal example.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). An MRE/SSCCE would be a lot shorter, and contain no cruft that's irrelevant to a layout problem (like Java Sound, action listeners, colors, custom fonts..). On a general note.. Seriously, you should be testing these types of things long before getting to **over 300 lines of code!**

Comment: 3) `jf.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson [Wow!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861243/why-after-i-added-components-to-jframe-instead-of-adding-them-to-jpanel-all-thes#comment108442115_60861243)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ugh.. I don't know why some people ask for help then ignore the advice offered.

Comment: [The Java Tutorials: A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) - reading that should make your life a lot easier. Or just skip to [How to Use SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) since you want to control the layout of everything.

Comment: @Elliott: I moved jf.setVisible(true); after jf.add(jp1); and got the same result. What I really want is not all listed here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry for the late response. I use jf.setLayout(null); and setBounds() for jPanel and other components, and it works fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to setBounds for jPanel, that's why the other component are covered up by the scope of jPanel. Now I put jp.setBounds(0,80,2200,1050) for jPanel and it's working fine now. The corrected code is list below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.IOException; 

class Panel1 extends JPanel{    
    public int x[] = new int[59]; 
    public int y[] = new int[59]; 
    public int width[] = new int[59];
    public int height = 20;
    public Color color[] = new Color[59];//the color of each note
    public String  str = "紫 竹調";

    String[] lyric = {" 一", " 根", "紫～", "竹", "直～", "苗～", "苗,",
                      "送", "給", "寶", "寶", "做", "管", " 簫,",
                      "簫", "兒", "對", "準", "口,", "口", "兒", "對", "準", "簫,", 
                      "簫～", "中", "吹～", "出", "新～", "時～ ", "調,",
                      "小", "寶～", "寶,", "小", "寶～", "寶,", 
                      "咿", "底", "咿", "底", " 學 ", "會", "了,", "啊 ～     ～    ～"};//共45個

    int[] numNotes = {1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                      2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1,
                      1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6};//共45個

    int[][] notes = {{5,2},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},{2,1},{1,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {3,1},{5,1},{6,2},{3,2},{5,8},{8,1},{6,1},{3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{6,1},{5,1},
                     {3,1},{6,1},{5,4},{5,1},{6,1},{8,2},{6,1},{5,1},{3,2},{5,1},{2,1},{3,1},
                     {2,1},{1,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{1,2},{1,1},{3,1},{2,4},{6,1},{8,1},
                     {6,1},{8,1},{9,2},{6,2},{5,3},{6,1},{2,1},{3,1},{5,1},{6,1},{5,8}};//共59個

    String[] simplifiedNote = {"  5", "  1", " 6", "5", "3", "  5", " 2", " 3", "2", "1  - ",
                               "  6", " 1"," 3", " 5", " 6", " 3", "  5  -  -  -", 
                               " 1", " 6", " 3", " 6", " 5  - ", " 6", " 5", " 3", " 6", " 5  -",
                               " 5", " 6", " 1", " 6", "5", " 3", " 5", "2", " 3"," 2", "1   -", 
                               " 1", " 1", "3", "2   -", " 1", " 1", "3", "2  -",
                               " 6", "1","6", "1", " 2", "6", " 5 ．", "6", 
                               " 2", "3", " 5", "6", " 5  -  -  - "};//共59個

    Color color0 = new Color(255,255,255); //白色 
    Color color1 = new Color(255,0,0); //紅色
    Color color2 = new Color(255,165,0); //橙色
    Color color3 = new Color(255,255,0); //黃色
    Color color4 = new Color(0,128,0); //綠色
    Color color5 = new Color(0,0,255); //藍色
    Color color6 = new Color(75,0,130); //靛色
    Color color7 = new Color(100,0,153); //紫色
    Color color8 = new Color(153,0,0); //暗紅
    Color color9 = new Color(0,0,0); //黑色

    //Constructor for initializing the color, y position, width, length of each note
    Panel1(){
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++) {
            //System.out.println("notes[" + i + "][0] = " + notes[i][0]);
            switch (notes[i][0]) {
                case 1:
                     y[i] = 400;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 2:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20;
                     color[i] = color2;
                     break;
                case 3:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*2;
                     color[i] = color3;
                     break;
                case 4:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*3;
                     color[i] = color4;
                     break;
                case 5:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*4;
                     color[i] = color5;
                     break;
                case 6:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*5;
                     color[i] = color6;
                     break;
                case 7:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*6;
                     color[i] = color7;
                     break;
                case 8:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*7;
                     color[i] = color1;
                     break;
                case 9:
                     y[i] = 400 - 20*8;
                     color[i] = color2;
            }

            switch (notes[i][1]) {
                case 1: width[i] = 20;     
                        break;
                case 2: width[i] = 20 * 2; 
                        break;
                case 3: width[i] = 20 * 3; 
                        break;
                case 4: width[i] = 20 * 4; 
                        break;
                case 5: width[i] = 20 * 5; 
                        break;
                case 6: width[i] = 20 * 6; 
                        break;
                case 7: width[i] = 20 * 7; 
                        break;
                case 8: width[i] = 20 * 8;
            }
        }

        x[0] = 100;
        for (int i = 1; i < notes.length; i++){
             x[i] = x[i-1] + width[i-1];
        }
    }

    public void display1(){
        //*
        int timeLast = 0;
        //timeLast = total executing time
        while(timeLast < 1000){ 
            for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i ++){
                x[i]--;
            }
            this.repaint(); 
            try {Thread.sleep(30);}
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timeLast = timeLast + 1; 
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);    
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 20));

        int y0 = 70; //歌名 之Y坐標
        int y1 = 130; //C調 4/4 Y坐標
        int y2 = 180; //簡譜行Y坐標
        int y3 = 210; //歌詞行Y坐標
        int y4 = 163; //加高音點
        int y5 = 180; //加八分音符底線
        int y6 = 470; //色彩音符說明

        int chrPosition = 0;

        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g2d.drawString(str, 550, y0);//繪出歌名

        g2d.setColor(color8); 
        g2d.drawLine(548,y0+8,660,y0+8);  //在歌名底下繪直橫線1
        g2d.drawLine(548,y0+10,660,y0+10);//在歌名底下繪直橫線2

        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.BOLD, 20));
        g2d.drawString("C調  4/4", 16, y1); //繪出調號節拍

        //繪出最底下的色彩音符說明
        g2d.drawString("色彩音符說明：", 16, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color1);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(176, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Do", 200, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color2);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(256, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//220 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Re", 280, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color3);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(336, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//230 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Mi", 360, y6);

        g2d.setColor(color4);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(416, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//322 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": Fa", 440, y6);//366 + 24

        g2d.setColor(color5);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(496, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//390 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": So", 520, y6);//446 + 24

        g2d.setColor(color6);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(576, y6-16, 20,20, 3,3);//470 + 56
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString(": La", 600, y6);

        //在簡譜下方寫出歌詞
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        for (int i = 0;  i < lyric.length; i++){
            if (i != 0 && numNotes[i-1] == 2) {
                chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            else {
                g2d.drawString(lyric[i], x[chrPosition], y3);
            }
            chrPosition = chrPosition + 1;
        }

        //在簡譜上方加高音點
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[1]+14, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[11]+8, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[17]+7, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[29]+8, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[47]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[49]+2, y4);
        g2d.drawString(".", x[50]+8, y4);
        //*
        //在簡譜下方加八分音符底線
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[2]+5,y5+5,x[4]-10,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[5]+10,y5+5,x[7]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[7]+3,y5+5,x[9]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[10]+10,y5+5,x[11],y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[11]+5,y5+5,x[12]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[12]+5,y5+5,x[13]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[13]+5,y5+5,x[14]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[17]+5,y5+4,x[18]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[18]+5,y5+4,x[19]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[19]+5,y5+4,x[20]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[20]+5,y5+4,x[21]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[22]+5,y5+5,x[23]-2,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[23]+5,y5+5,x[24]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[24]+5,y5+5,x[25]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[25]+5,y5+5,x[26]-5,y5+5);

        g2d.drawLine(x[27]+5,y5+5,x[29]-3,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[30]+1,y5+5,x[32]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[33]+5,y5+4,x[35]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[35]+5,y5+4,x[37]-5,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[39]+5,y5+4,x[41]-8,y5+4);
        g2d.drawLine(x[43]+5,y5+5,x[45]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[46]+5,y5+5,x[47]-5,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[47],y5+5,x[48]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[48],y5+5,x[49]-10,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[49],y5+5,x[50]-8,y5+5);
        g2d.drawLine(x[53]-2,y5+4,x[58]-5,y5+4);

        //在歌詞下方繪出彩色譜        
        for (int i = 0;i < notes.length; i++){

            //畫簡譜小節線
            g2d.setColor(color9);
            if (i==0||i==5||i==10||i==16||i==17||i==22||i==27||i==33||i==38||
                i==42||i==46||i == 52||i == 58) {
                g2d.drawString("|", x[i], y2);
                }

            //畫出簡譜
            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawString(simplifiedNote[i], x[i], y2);

            g2d.setColor(color[i]);
            g2d.fillRoundRect(x[i], y[i], width[i], height, 3,3); //畫圓角方塊

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],230, x[i]+width[i], 230);//畫水平上線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],231, x[i], 429);//畫直紅線

            g2d.setColor(color8);
            g2d.drawLine(x[i],430, x[i]+width[i], 430);//畫水平下線
        }
        g2d.setColor(color9);
        g2d.drawString("|",x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1]-5 , y2);
        g2d.drawString("|",x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1]-10 , y2);
        g2d.setColor(color8);
        g2d.drawLine(x[notes.length-1]+ width[notes.length - 1],231, x[notes.length - 1] + width[notes.length - 1],429);//畫邊界直紅線
    }
}

public class Move1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
    {
        JFrame  jf = new JFrame("康樂彩歌(v0)");
        jf.setBounds(0, 0, 1368, 730);      
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(null);

        Panel1 jp = new Panel1();
        jp.setBounds(0,80,2200,1050); // ***This line setBounds for jPanel

        JComboBox cmbox = new JComboBox();
        cmbox.setBounds(10, 40, 250, 40);
        cmbox.setLocation(370,25);
        cmbox.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        cmbox.addItem("紫竹調");
        cmbox.addItem("郊遊");
        cmbox.addItem("我家門前有小河");
        jf.add(cmbox);

        JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton("加人聲", false);
        rb.setFont(new Font("新細明體", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        rb.setBounds(635, 28, 90, 30);
        jf.add(rb);

        JButton btPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btPlay.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));
        btPlay.setBounds(740, 25, 100, 40);
        jf.add(btPlay);

        JButton btStop = new JButton("STOP");
        btStop.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG_INPUT, Font.BOLD, 25));
        btStop.setBounds(850, 25, 100, 40);
        jf.add(btStop);

        jf.setVisible(true);

        jf.add(jp);
        jp.display1();
     }
}
```